# Jxplore query for searching the data from ldap active directory which is not memberOf OU=Corporate nor CN= google app use

Tags: ldap, jndi, openldap

I  am facing a problem in searching the data  from the active directory using the jexplore.  I Really appreciate if  anyone can help me writing filter query for  memberOf attribute of User which is **neither CN=Google Apps Users nor OU=corporate**

```
     (|(!(memberOf~=OU=corporate))(!(memberOf~=CN=Google Apps Users ))) //query 1

     (&(!(memberOf=*OU=Corporate*))(!(memberOf=*OU=Google Apps Users)))//query 2

  (&(!(ou=Corporate))(!(ou=Google Apps Users))) //query 3
```

but these query is  showing all  user which are having  CN=Google Apps Users,Ou=Corporate or not

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your LDAP Structure is form the question, but try something like

```
(&(!(ou:dn:=Corporate))(!(memberOf=CN=Google Apps Users,Ou=Corporate)))
```

Which uses an extensible match as shown at: http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch